# Column sum of only visible row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to calculate the sum of the grand total column and showing it to the footer of the gridview, which I am able to achieve it. However I have a condition which makes some rows invisible from the gridview, but it is also summing the value of the rows which are invisible. How to sum the column value only for the rows which are visible?

Below is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView9" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ShowFooter="true" BackColor="White" DataKeyNames="ID" BorderColor="#999999" CssClass="tableUserInfo"
            GridLines="Vertical" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="10" OnRowDataBound="GridView9_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SessionId" Visible="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_GSessionId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SessionId") %>' ReadOnly="true"
                            Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer" Visible="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" Font-Size="11px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="8%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="G_Total" Visible="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblGTotal" Font-Size="11px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GTotal","{0:n}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle Width="30%" />
                    <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="8%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="Red" Width="100%" Wrap="false" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
decimal grdTotal;
protected void GridView9_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    txt_SessionId.Text = ddlSession.SelectedValue;
    foreach (GridViewRow row2 in GridView9.Rows)
    {
        TextBox sid = row2.FindControl("txt_GSessionId") as TextBox;
        int a, b;
        a = int.Parse(sid.Text);
        b = int.Parse(txt_SessionId.Text);
        if (a == b)
        {
            row2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            row2.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    if (e.Row.Visible && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        decimal rowTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "GTotal"));
        grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal;
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
        Label lbl1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLabourTotal");
        lbl.Font.Size = 12;
        lbl.Text = "Rs. " + grdTotal.ToString("0");
        lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you loop all GridView rows for each row in this GridView(RowDataBound is called for every Row). That nested loop is surely not what you want

Comment: @ Rango because I want to align sessionId (txt_SessionId), which is the category ID of the record that are displayed in the gridview9. However when the gridview9 is bind through store procedure it displays all the records, therefore to filter the record, the gridview9 sessionId (txt_GSessionId) should align (equals) with the sessionId of (txt_Sessionid). Hence I am looping through all the records in the gridview9 to check if sessionId of gridview (txt_GSessionId) is matching with the sessionId in txt_SessionId (tetbox).